# Проблемы с Xcode 14

Tags: ios, xcode

После обновления до MacOS Ventura обновился и мой Xcode до 14 версии.
Проблема в том, что с ним невозможно работать. Каждое 3-е действие приводится к крашу IDE, а аналогов так и не придумали. Кто и как справляется с этой проблемой?
Вот с какими проблемами встречаюсь я:
п

1. После нажатия комбинации `cmd + z` краш IDE
2. Каждый 2-й или 3-й запуск симулятора приводит к черному экрану, в данном случае нужно перезагружать весь симулятор что отнимает очень много времени.
3. Нажатие на кнопку включения `Code Review`
4. Почему-то `Variables View` перестал отображать корректную информацию. Иногда может написать, что нужное мне значение nil (но проверяя в консоли вы начинаете понимать, что это значение совсем не nil).
5. Вы подумаете, да что такого, раз работает консоль то можно откинуть 4-й пункт. А нет, нельзя, потому что иногда и консоль с print object не работает.
6. По сравнению с Xcode 13, в 14-й версии время компиляции значительно увеличилось, при том что я через fastlane скрипт собираю все приложение и отправляю сборку в firebase за 2 минуты. Но стоит подправить что-то через Xcode, и время компиляции возрастает в геометрической прогресии.

Мне интересно, это я придирчивый, или эти вещи только у меня в принципе встречаются? Я не нашел ничего подобного в интернете.

Comment: я так понимаю переустановка не помогла?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не помогла

Comment: Аналог есть, называется AppCode. Но сегодня анонсировали, что его поддержка заканчивается :)